# About preventing Listview.Builder() to rebulding it all items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting users data from firebase by stream builder,
And I am rendering those data using Listview.builder(),
one problem is that when I get **snapshot** from firestore my all items in listview.builder() is rebuilding.
how do I prevent this thing ***reRendering or Rebuilding()***

Hear is my Code

```
class GetUser extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("// <1> Use StreamBuilder");
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        // <2> Pass `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` to stream
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // <3> Retrieve `List<DocumentSnapshot>` from snapshot
            final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.docs;
            //documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc));
            print(documents.length);
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                      addRepaintBoundaries: false,
                      itemCount: documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return  Items(
                          doc: documents[i],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error");
          } else {
            return Text("Waiting");
          }
        });
  }
}

//this Item class is invoked every time I add a user to the collection

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot doc;
  const Item({Key key, this.doc}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemState createState() => _ItemState();
}


class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Build called ${widget.doc.id}");
    return Text("${widget.doc["full_name"]}--${widget.doc.id}");
  }
}
```

Comment: remove `SingleChildScrollView`, and `Column` and `SizedBox`

Comment: Not working @pskink and i can not remove SizedBox because it causes rendering problem

Comment: what not working?

Comment: by removing sizedBox I am getting this error
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#09c2d relayoutBoundary=up22 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists - it does not work too?

Comment: I Removed SizedBox too but still, it rerendering all items when a new item is added in a stream

Comment: no, it renders only visible items - if you have for example 1000 items and you add one another item only 7 -10 items will be renderd depending on item and screen size

Comment: Thanks, bro its worked, If I scroll then-new Items is rendered please correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: you are not wrong